# ROS 2 lifecycle node self-transitioning

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experimenting with giving one of my nodes a lifecycle:

From the ROS 2 [node lifecycle design document](http://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html) in regards to  the management interface of lifecycle nodes:

> It is expected that a common pattern
> will be to have a container class
> which loads a managed node
> implementation from a library and
> through a plugin architecture
> automatically exposes the required
> management interface via methods and
> the container is not subject to the
> lifecycle management. ... These
> services may also be provided via
> attributes and method calls (for local
> management) in addition to being
> exposed ROS messages and
> topics/services (for remote
> management).

Also from the design document, in the section after the above in regards to transitioning among the lifecycle states:

> Most state transitions are expected to
> be coordinated by an external
> management tool which will provide the
> node with its configuration and start
> it. The external management tool is
> also expected monitor it and execute
> recovery behaviors in case of
> failures. ... And a node could be
> configured to self manage, however
> this is discouraged as this will
> interfere with external logic trying
> to manage the node via the interface.
>
> There is one transition expected to
> originate locally, which is the `ERROR`
> transition.

So the lifecycle command line utilities and lifecycle rqt plugins would be examples of external management tools referenced.  I would also classify the python launch files that control the lifecycle to be external tools (that could fight with the command line/rqt tools since the python launch files will be automatic). But even if it's discouraged, I think my node will need to self-transition. Maybe a container class like the one referenced could do the self transitioning I require, though I'm not sure. So...

Are there any examples of lifecycle nodes self-transitioning with the `ERROR` transition or examples of container classes that orchestrate lifecycle transitions of loaded node implementations? I can find the lifecycle code and demos for rclcpp_lifecycle, but no nice documented API page.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348583/ros-2-lifecycle-node-self-transitioning/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transition from active to error processing does not exist in the current lifecycle state machine, so as it is, this is currently impossible. [This question](https://answers.ros.org/question/302178/ros2-managed-node-triggering-an-error-from-primary-state/) and [this issue (which was marked as a duplicate)](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/547) is essentially the same as mine. The answer there says to trigger change of state manually with the `configure`, `cleanup`, `activate`, `deactivate`, and `shutdown` member functions of lifecycle node, even though that was "discouraged" in the design document. However I think there is use for a transition directly from active to error processing as well as from inactive to error processing.

I have created a series of pull requests implementing this functionality: [rcl_interfaces#97](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/pull/97), [rcl#618](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/618), [rclcpp#1064](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/1064), and to show how it is used, [demos#436](https://github.com/ros2/demos/pull/436).

It would still be nice to have an example of the container class. I may ask that in another question later on, but for now, my new error transition will meet my needs.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2020-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2